# nodejs SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm

I am using `elasticsearch-exporter` to export data from `Elasticsearch`.

The tool initially is a `nodejs` application.

When I try to use the following command `node exporter.js` to make the tool list all the available options, it crashes with the following exception

```
/home/me/storage/Elasticsearch-Exporter/log.js:54
exports.error = (...args) => !capture("ERROR", args) && console.log(timestamp() + util.format(...args).red);
                 ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anas/storage/Elasticsearch-Exporter/exporter.js:9:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

here is the line where the exception is thrown

```
exports.error = (...args) => !capture("ERROR", args) && console.log(timestamp() + util.format(...args).red);
```

I think the error is related to a different version of nodejs but I am not sure.

Here is the output of the `node --version` command `v4.2.6`

Here is the output of the `npm --version` command `3.10.6`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, indeed, `...` is called the [**spread operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and is only available since Node.js 6

The elasticsearch-exporter project [declares in its `package.json` file](https://github.com/mallocator/Elasticsearch-Exporter/blob/master/package.json#L91-L93) that it only works with node version > 6

So since you're running Node.js 4.2.6, you either need to upgrade your Node.js installation or fork the elasticsearch-exporter project and modify it to work with Node.js 4.2.6.